# How to store total resulted from the calculation of two UI params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

Lets say I have a model `Staff` with only two attributes: `name` and `hours`.

I have a form like the below, where `start` and `finish` are virtual attribute:

```
<%= form_for(@staff) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :start %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :start %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :finish %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :finish %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

In my database, I would like to save the `name` and the `hours` (`hours` is the difference between `finish` and `start`).

My question is: what is the best approach to calculate and save the `hours` on my database? There is a way to create a method on the `Staff` model or I need to do the calculation in the `create` and in the `update` actions of my controller?

Comment: You can use a callback. `before_save :calculate_hours`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper way is to do it in your model and make a `before_save` or a `before_create` callback. Try something like this :

```
before_save :set_hours

def set_hours
  self.hours = finish - start
end
```

Hope this helps.